# if/else if conditions in flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to play a sound if the conditions met in my `if` statement and I do NOT want to play sound if the conditions change in my `else if` statement.

however, this doesn't work and no matter what, the sound always plays.

This is my current AS3 code:

```
    if (myText_txt_timesUp.text == "Less Than 10 Minutes Left!" && extInfoTxt.text == "")
    {
            mySoundMc.gotoAndPlay(2);

    }   else if (myText_txt_timesUp.text == "Less Than 10 Minutes Left!" && extInfoTxt.text == "No Extension Was Added.")
    {
mySoundMc.gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: what happens in mySoundMc frame 1 and 2?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko, A SOUND WILL BE PLAYED.

Comment: Change `gotoAndPlay(1)` to `gotoAndStop(1)` after the `else if`.

Comment: How exactly a sound will be played? Can you show the code which plays sound in frame 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience playing sound inside a movieclip is not a good idea in AS3. Unlike AS2 in AS3 sound plays as a separate instance. The way i manage sound is create a singleton or static class on which i control the sound for the whole project.

Comment: +1, although there is more setup up front, this route usually saves me more time in the long run and allows for better control.

Answer (score 0):

You have it set to gotoAndPlay for both if and else instead change the else to gotoAndStop

```
if (myText_txt_timesUp.text == "Less Than 10 Minutes Left!" && extInfoTxt.text == "")
{
        mySoundMc.gotoAndPlay(2);

}   else if (myText_txt_timesUp.text == "Less Than 10 Minutes Left!" &&     extInfoTxt.text == "No Extension Was Added.")
{
mySoundMc.gotoAnd**Stop**(1);
}
```